# How to do container rollbacks using a multi docker configuration on elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

I'm using EB to run multiple Docker containers using there **multi docker configuration** which makes use of ECS.

I want to find out how I can manage container rollbacks? At the moment if I push something to **GitHub**, my code-pipeline initiates a code-build, my code-build then push the built container to our ECS registry with the **latest** tag.

I have setup my **image** inside the container definition which points to the **latest** container. Now I believe **EB** automatically pulls the new containers - This can cause problem as I don't have a way to fallback to the previous version if something fails inside of it.

Our flow looks like this:

1. Push to git
2. Codebuild -> Push built container to ECS registry
3. EB points to the **latest** image

What our flow needs to look like:

1. Push to git
2. Codebuild -> Push built container to ECS registry
3. EB points to the **latest** image
4. Does the node app fail? Is there an error? If so: **roll back to the previous container version**

Answer (score 0):

Latest tag is evil, especially with autoscaling group.

As I can see you have 2 options

1. You can use [blue/green deployment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html)
2. You can use [immutable environment updates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environmentmgmt-updates-immutable.html)